# $f(t)^2<1+2\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\:ds$ Then prove that $f(t)<1+t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, continuity, monotone-functions, leibniz-integral-rule

Given that $f:[0,1]\to [0, \infty)$ be a continuous function such that
$$f(t)^2<1+2\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\:ds,\:\forall t \in [0,1] \to (1)$$
Then prove that $$f(t)<1+t ,\forall t \in [0,1]$$

I actually got the solution in this way:
Differentiating $(1)$ both sides with respect to $t$ and using Leibnitz rule we have
$$2f(t)f'(t)<2f(t) \to (2)$$
$\implies$
$$2f(t)\left(f'(t)-1\right)<0$$
Now since the range of $f(t)$ cannot be negative,we get
$$f'(t)-1<0$$
$\implies$
$f(t)-t$ is a strictly decreasing function in $t \in [0,1]$
So we get
$$f(t)-t<f(0)-0 \to (3)$$
Now in $(1)$ plugging in $t=0$ we get
$$f(0)^2<1 \implies f(0)<1$$
So using $f(0)<1$ in $(3)$ we get
$$f(t)-t<1 \implies f(t)<1+t, \forall t \in [0,1]$$
Now my query is in getting $(2)$. After differentiation how can we be sure that inequality is retained. Am i missing any concept there?

Comment: It isn't true that if $f(t) < g(t)$ then $f'(t) < g'(t)$, so you simply can't make that step.

Comment: Yes that is my issue. looking for corrections.

Comment: What does the notation $\forall t \in [0,1] \to (1)$ in the first display mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, the inequality is true for all such $t$

Comment: that makes little sense to me. when you say "for all such $t$" could you clarify exactly what you mean? All $t$ such that _what_, exactly? (It _appears_ that you meant "all $t$ such that $t\in[0,1]$ and $t\to(1)$", but that's meaningless; there's no such thing as _a_ number which tends to zero.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds$ and  $h(t)=\sqrt{1+2g(t)}-t-1,$ h is a continuously differentiable function.

I observe that
$$h'(t)=\frac{g'(t)}{\sqrt{1+2g(t)}}-1<0.$$
So, $$h(t)\leq h(0)=0\Rightarrow 1+2g(t)\leq (1+t)^2$$ and as a consequence
$$f(t)<1+t.$$